# How to break an image in triangle pieces

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image

I'm trying to fragment an image into several smaller triangles in WPF or Silverlight. I've looked around but most of the cropping looks like its done using the clone method which only takes a rectangle.

Comment: WPF or Silverlight? Its best to be specific, what is available in WPF may not be in Silverlight.